# Having trouble parsing tcpdump output with regex

Tags: regex, networking, tcpdump

In particular, I'm trying to get the "Host: ..." part of an HTTP header of the HTTP request packet.

One instance is something like this:

.$..2~.:Ka3`..E..D'.@.@..M....J}.e...P...q...W................g.o3GET./.HTTP/1.1...$..2~.:Ka3`..E..G'.@.@..I....J}.e...P.......W................g..\host:.domain.com..

Another is this:

.$..2~.:Ka3`..E..D'.@.@..M....J}.e...P...q...W................g.o3GET./.HTTP/1.1...$..2~.:Ka3`..E..G'.@.@..I....J}.e...P.......W................g..\host:.domain.com..Connection:.Keep-Alive....

Note this is the ascii output. I want to extract that host. My initial regex was:

```
[hH]ost:\.(.*)..
```

This works for the first case, but does not work for the second one. In particular, for the second one it will extract: "domain.com..Connection.Keep-Alive.."

I would appreciate some help with creating a general regex that works in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?<=host:\.)(?:\.?[^.])+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yR6mA5)

- The lookbehind `(?<=host:\.)` asserts that what precedes is `host:.`
- `(?:\.?[^.])` matches an optional period, then one character that is not a period.
- And the `+` makes us match one or more of these characters

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI added demo, explanation  and reference. :)

Comment: Is there a way to have group(0) be 'domain.com' instead of host:.domain.com so that I dont have to regex twice?

Comment: Done (see revised regex and demo). Please let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: @zx81 Why we need a negative-lookahead just `(?<=host:\.)(?:[^.]|\.[^.])+` will work perfectly.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, that's another option. Why one and not the other? It just came out that way when I wrote it. There are always 10 ways of writing the same thing. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Changed it to option 3 which is a touch more compact: `(?<=host:\.)(?:\.?[^.])+` Of course there are always other ways. :)